# Symfony built in language parser

Tags: php, symfony, twig, multilingual

So, i'v used to use such method to prevent the views from being "dirty" with hardcoded values inside of the html tags:

Instead of using:

```
<div>Greetengs!</div>
```

I like to use (With Twig):

```
<div>{{ lang.greetengs }}</div>
```

With such code in the model:

```
<?php

    /*
    * Simple example
    */

    $data['lang'] = parse_ini_file(PATH_TO_LANG_FILE);
    echo $template->render($data);
```

Now I want to use Symfony for my projects. And I know that i can do the same thing there,
but **the question is:**

Is there a built-in mechanism in Symfony to do the same thing i'v shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one it's really well documented here : [Translation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)

Then in you're twig view you'll just have to do this :

```
{{ 'greetengs' | trans }} // Trans being the value of locale stored in session ( 'en', 'de', 'fr' ...) or in the
```